# A complex problem on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Show that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are acute angles such that :

$$\left[\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta)\sin \beta\right]^2=4 \cos \alpha \cos \beta\sin(\alpha+\beta)$$

then $$\tan \alpha =\tan \beta \left[\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{2}\cos \beta-1)^2}-1\right]$$

I tried to use componendo dividendo  to prove the statement but got nowhere.

I don't get how to simplify or operate on the $\sqrt{2}\cos\beta - 1$ part.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216316/help-with-a-complex-trigonometry-problem

Comment: Why are you posting the same question twice? (Just want to attract attention?)

Comment: Please help me fjnd solution to this problem. It was not answered before so i reposted it

Comment: Not receiving answers is not a reason for reposting anyway.

Comment: From [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) :  Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.

Comment: Never repost a question : imagine that all questions that haven't been answered a day are reposted next day... Moreover (personal opinion), your last questions about trigonometry are very very intricated ; is it an instructor that asks you such bizarre questions ?

Comment: Sure. I shall keep in mind these things. No the problems are from a book of india. I am self studying.

Comment: There must be an error in your text : if I take $a=0.5$ (radians, not degrees) and $b=1.06679684$ radians, the first identity is verified till the 9th decimal, but the second is not at all verified : LHS=0.5463 whereas RHS = 16.2271...

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\sin A(\cos B-\sin B\sin2B)+\cos A(\cos2B\sin B-\sin B)$$
$$=\sin A\cos B\cos2B-2\cos A\sin^3B$$

Divide both sides of the given condition by $\cos^2A\cos^B$ to find

$$(\tan A\cos2B-2\sin^2B\tan B)^2=4(\tan A+\tan B)$$

$$\iff((\tan A+\tan B)\cos2B-\tan B)^2=4(\tan A+\tan B)$$

Rearrange to form a quadratic equation in $\tan A+\tan B$

Finally find the roots of the equation